# Netbeans (and other Java apps) runs slow on Linux

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

I would like to create Java applications, but my first  “brake” is that it is impossible to run Netbeans at a decent speed under Ubuntu 9.10 with a Radeon X1300 Pro graphics card, P4 3.2GHz.

If I use other software, like Monodevelop or any other **non**-Java app, I don’t have this run-slow problem.

This could perhaps be my Radeon card with my high resolution  (1600x1050), so would I be better off if I bought another video card? Or is it a problem with Linux, the Java Virtual Machine or something else?

Are there any settings I should try changing in the netbeans.conf file? Would setting `opengl=true` or any other settings improve my Netbeans experience?

If you can run Netbeans without problems, what PC configuration do you have?

I know this is not strictly a programming question, but it is about developer tools and configuration.

Comment: Are you using sun's java or the open source java? What exactly is slow about it? Have you tried eclipse?

Comment: I think SO is probably appropriate although Superuser might be a good place to ask about Linux performance in general.

Comment: The JDK matters - OpenJDK does appear to be slower than the Sun JDK

Comment: @Falmarri: in particular is slow the "refresh" of video. I click on menu and..wait.. after 1-2 seconds it opens. Other thing is slow: the autocomplete feature.. i've to wait a lot of seconds, also the gui builder .. I think it's something related to my operating system installation... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your CPU speed is fine.
- Your video card is powerful enough.  Video driver issues are possible, but not terribly likely.
- NetBeans is RAM-hungry, there's just no way around it:

  - Make sure you have enough free physical RAM on your machine when running NetBeans.  Ask Google for information about how to inspect and watch memory usage for your OS.
  - Maybe try closing one or two other RAM-hungry apps, if you have them running.
  - Try using the Sun JDK/JRE, it is more heavily optimized than other offerings.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should check your java virtual machine, i have used netbeans on various machines for java development and got no problems up to now.

Answer (score 1):

I've run Netbeans on Ubuntu 9.10 and a Radeon card with no problems. One thing you may want to do is increase the memory size that the JVM allocates to Netbeans. [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetBeansAndOOME) Netbeans wiki article should help you figure out how to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally noticed Netbeans slowness on Fedora 14 under a couple conditions:

1. Using OpenJDK seems to be slower than Sun Java
2. Using the `radeon` open source video driver

I've been meaning to install `fglrx` on my laptop to confirm this hypothesis about #2. See [this](http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?p=1374666) thread for more.

Comment: I confirm hypothesis #1, on Fedora 21